# How to connect the two mouths of a wormhole in embedding diagram?

Tags: plotting

here's the code that I've been using:

```
z[r_, q_, b0_] := I r Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/(1 - q), 
 1 + 1/(1 - q), (r/b0)^(1 - q)] - I b0 Sqrt[Pi] Gamma[1 + 1/(1 - q)]/Gamma[1/2 + 1/(1 - q)];

RevolutionPlot3D[{{r, z[r, 0, 5]}, {r, -z[r, 0, 5]}}, {r, 0, 7}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Magenta, Opacity[0.4], Specularity[White, 10]],
MeshStyle -> Blue, PlotPoints -> 30, Boxed -> False,PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False]
```

here's the result that I get
[image]

How can I smoothly connect the two mouths of the wormhole smoothly?

Comment: If you connect the 2 mouths, you get a torus (eventually distorted). There is graphics primitive "Torus".

Comment: If you think my answer is satisfactory/helpful, please consider accepting it (click the green tick on the side).

Answer (score 4):

The function `z[r, 0, 5]` is complex for $r<5$ and this causes sampling issues with `RevolutionPlot3D`. Thus, making the plot in the range $r\in[5,10]$ gives much better results and the wormhole now looks continuous:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{r, z[r, 0, 5]}, {r, -z[r, 0, 5]}}, {r, 5, 10}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Magenta, Opacity[0.4], Specularity[White, 10]], MeshStyle -> Blue, PlotPoints -> 30, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False]
```

[image]